# Allow to read and delete but not create files in linux directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

There are plenty of questions dealing with the [opposite case](https://superuser.com/questions/152161/is-it-possible-to-forbid-removal-of-files-but-allow-creation-of-them-for-specifi) [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869536/linux-directory-permissions-read-write-but-not-delete), but I've not managed to find an answer for this way round.

Is it possible to set permissions on a linux directory such that a user may read and delete files already present, but not create new ones?

I suspect not as it seems like delete must require 'write' access to the directory, but I'd be happy to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is no, you can't do what you are asking with the existing file permissions system.  Delete will require write access, and even the sticky bit on the directory will only prevent deletes/renames by non-owners, there is no reverse equivalent.

I suppose there might be a way to do this with [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) but that would be a *lot* of work - if you are going to go to that sort of trouble, an application to control access would be a lot more flexible.

Finally, if this is simply about changing/updating/removing files, I would probably use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) to allow someone to change whatever they like on their local copy but then have to submit a pull request (or get permission to check in etc.) their changes to the master copy.  It requires a workflow change but gives you nice ways to roll back, reject changes etc.

Comment: This is a log file directory so we wanted to allow the user to manually clear it out but not to be able to modify the logs - looks like either deleting the oldest automatically or trusting the user to not screw the files up is the answer then. :)

Comment: Ah, in that case you could use the sticky bit, or permissions in general to stop them from screwing them up and use a cron job, or one of the standard (configurable) log rotation utilities to automatically manage it.  Generally, I've found that something like: archive anything older than 1 week (compress) and then delete anything older than 6 months works well, but it depends on the use case.

Comment: Just for reference, logrotate is pretty standard these days, and there are other options too: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html